# Resize a Image Picked from Gallery to Image View

Tags: android, image, resize, gallery

My App have an activity with a ImageView where i pick a picture from phone gallery and set in this ImageView as user's profile picture.

My problem is that some pictures when picked make app stop cause is too big, i want to know if someone can look my code and help me how can i resize this picked picture, so after set in this image view, how can user cut this picture before set, here below is my code where i pic the picture. i will be so greatful if someone do the needed changes and give me the code cause i dont know so much about developing. thank you.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("picturePath", picturePath).commit();
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.User);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

    }
```

Comment: Try this is image compression like whtsapp I have used in my application https://www.built.io/blog/2013/03/improving-image-compression-what-weve-learned-from-whatsapp/

Answer (score 0):

Not gonna rewrite your code but this could be useful

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(foto.getFotoOrderFilePath());
    Double height = (double)bitmap.getHeight();
    Double scalingFactor = (960.0/height);
    int tempWidht = bitmap.getWidth();
    Double Dwidth = (tempWidht*scalingFactor);
    int width = Dwidth.intValue();
    Log.v("bitmap dimensions: ", String.valueOf(height) + " + " +String.valueOf(width) + " + " + String.valueOf(scalingFactor));
    bitmap = Utilities.scaleBitmap(bitmap, width, 960);
```

An excerpt from code I use to scale a bitmap down. It sets the hight to 960 and get the scaling to change the width accordingly.

edit:

the ScaleBitmap method.

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int wantedWidth, int wantedHeight) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(wantedWidth, wantedHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.setScale((float) wantedWidth / bitmap.getWidth(), (float) wantedHeight / bitmap.getHeight());
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, new Paint());
    return output;
}
```

sorry for the late response

Comment: i dont understando so well about coding, where should i add this in my code? thank you again :) i am begining with coding .

Comment: i added to my code, but this line "bitmap = Utilities.scaleBitmap(bitmap, width, 960);" the Ultilities stay red, and the first bitmap stay as unused.

Comment: Ah forgot that, will post that code next monday if you still need it

Comment: Yes, i still need ..;)

Comment: you should pull from imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); the decode part out of the method and then edit your bitmap as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is image compression like whtsapp I have used in my application https://www.built.io/blog/2013/03/improving-image-compression-what-weve-learned-from-whatsapp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso library. Get it from [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/).
The syntax looks like this:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imagePath).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to resize image as per your requirement

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String Filepath,
                                                  int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Filepath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Filepath, options);
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // Raw height and width of image
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;


    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

check here
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: but where and how i must call decodeSampledBitmapFromResource ? thank you.

Comment: @JaquelineRosa once you get image path pass that to this method and you will get resized bitmap from it then set it into imageview. I hope you understand it.